# could not load library for oracle_fdw

Tags: postgresql, oracle11g, foreign-data-wrapper, oracle-fdw

I am facing issue while creating oracle_fdw.

I have copied oracle_fdw.dll to postgres lib folder * 
both .sql file and control file to shrared/extension

now when I connect to psql with superadmin user & make an query

```
 create extension oracle_fdw;
```

I am getting response

```
ERROR:  could not load library "D:/postgresdb/lib/oracle_fdw.dll": The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Answer (score 1):

From the error it seems that the oracle_fdw library is not available in the lib folder of postGreSQL installation directory.

You may download the Oracle fdw extension/or library file from  https://github.com/laurenz/oracle_fdw/releases/ - please download the one suitable to your system environment(eg : 32bit windows/64bit).

Extract the downloaded .zip file.

1. copy the oracle_fdw.dll from \oracle_fdw-1.4.0-pg95-win64\lib folder to \Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\lib dir 
   &
   2.copy all the files from oracle_fdw-1.4.0-pg95-win64\share\extension  to \Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\share\extension

Now restart postGreSQL server and try.

Note : Always download and use compatible version of library; e.g.: PostgreSQL 9.5 version you should download same version of oracle_fdw zip.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem so this is what i did to resolve it. Not sure if all steps are needed since i was trying untill it worked.

Downloaded:

Instant Client Package

Instant Client Package - SQL*Plus

Instant Client Package - ODBC

From oracle (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html)

Unzipped everything to one folder (c:\oracle)

Ran odbc_install in that folder

Added folder to PATH variable (System properties - Environment variables)

Restarted postgresql server

After that it worked. Also notice that you need the same version as your server (x86, x64).

Hope this helps.