# ERROR: could not load library "oracle_fdw.dll": %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: database, postgresql, relational-database, foreign-data-wrapper, oracle-fdw

Things I've done, in order:

1. Downloaded and installed PostgreSQL server 9.5.7 64bit from entreprisedb.com, latest version for which oracle_fdw is available
2. Installed the other stuff (postGIS, Npgsql, pgAgent, etc), in 64bit variant where it gave me the choice, in the second part of the installation
3. Downloaded oracle_fdw-1.3.0-pg95-win64.zip from https://github.com/laurenz/oracle_fdw/releases/ and extracted all the files to where they are supposed to be, C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.5/....
4. Ran the following command in pgAdmin:

   CREATE EXTENSION oracle_fdw;

and I got the following error:

```
ERROR:  could not load library "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.5/lib/oracle_fdw.dll": %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Comment: have you checked [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38893806/could-not-load-library-for-oracle-fdw)?

Comment: Yes but he has a different problem. I tried both the 32bit and 64bit variants also. I've put them in the correct places.

Answer (score 2):

Either the `oracle_fdw.dll` is corrupt, or it not all of your software (Oracle client?) is 64-bit.

You will need a 64-bit Oracle client installed. See the [README](https://raw.github.com/laurenz/oracle_fdw/ORACLE_FDW_1_5_0/README.oracle_fdw):

> Oracle client version 10.1 or better is required.
>   oracle_fdw can be built and used with Oracle Instant Client as well as with
>   Oracle Client and Server installations installed with Universal Installer.
>   Binaries compiled with Oracle Client 10 can be used with later client versions
>   without recompilation or relink.

(There are oracle_fdw binaries for PostgreSQL 9.6 as well.)

Comment: I need an oracle client to make it work? I didn't know. I have Oracle SQL Developer but I don't think it's declared as system variable. Is there any tutorial/documentation on how to set up the Oracle client on Windows for oracle_fdw to work?

Comment: There is no way to connect to Oracle without an Oracle client, so yes, you'll need that as stated in the documentation of oracle_fdw. I recommend Oracle Instant Client and have to refer to the Oracle documentation. Open a Github issue if you have specific problems getting it to work. Normally your setup is fine if the PostgreSQL operating system user can connect to the Oracle database using sqlplus. The Oracle client library must be on the `PATH` of the PostgreSQL service.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarification. I think I missed point 5. of the documentation. Gonna study it and try to make it work.